# Is it possible to use Agda as a library?

Tags: haskell, agda

Instead of using Agda on a filesystem (with EMACS, terminal, etc.), is it possible to use it directly from Haskell, as a library? For example:

```
-- UsingAgda.hs
import Agda

-- Prints the type of a term on some Agda code
main :: IO ()
main = typeOf "true" agdaCode where

  agdaCode :: String
  agdaCode = unlines
    ["module Hello where   "
    ,"                     "
    ,"data Bool : Set where"
    ,"  true  : Bool       "
    ,"  false : Bool       "]
```

The code above would output `Bool`, because `true : Bool` on that Agda code.

Comment: FYI: you don't need `unlines` for a multiline string. The compiler will elide whitespace between two ``\``s in a string literal. You can have `"module Hello where \n\<ACTUAL NEWLINE><INDENT>\data Bool : Set where\n"` etc.

Comment: @HTNW not sure which one is ugliest, to be honest... JavaScript's back-ticks are missed here.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible. Agda was designed as a Haskell library plus a main module.

You can see a couple of small examples [here](https://github.com/agda/agda/tree/master/test/api). As a bigger example, I wrote [Apia](https://github.com/asr/apia) (shameless plug), which uses Agda as a library.

Please keep in mind that the *current* Agda [description](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Agda-2.5.3) says:

> Note that the Agda package does not follow the package versioning
>   policy, because it is not intended to be used by third-party packages.

Of course, it could change.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or something explaining how to use Agda as a library? I fear those examples won't suffice.