# Examples of using Idris as a pure Haskell library?

Tags: haskell, idris

I'm aware it should be possible, but, because of the lack of documentation, it'd require some considerable reverse engineering effort to figure out. As such, what is an example of using Idris as a Haskell library? Possible usage illustration:

```
import Idris

code :: String
code = unlines [
  "data Nat : Type where                ",
  "  Zero : Nat -> Nat                  ",
  "  Suc  : Nat                         ",
  "                                     ",
  "double : Nat -> Nat                  ",
  "double Zero    = Zero                ",
  "double (Suc n) = Suc (Suc (double n))",
  "                                     ",
  "n2 : Nat                             ",
  "n2 = double (Suc Zero)               "]

main :: IO ()
main = do

  -- prints "Nat -> Nat"
  print $ typeOf "double" code

  -- prints "Suc (Suc Zero)"
  print $ normOf "n2" code

  -- prints the context of a hole at given index
  print $ contextAt <index> code
```

Moreover, I wonder if such library would be pure (i.e., no system calls, String-based) and, thus, capable of being compiled by GHCJS. I've posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330226/is-it-possible-to-use-agda-as-a-library) about Agda (which didn't get the answer I needed, although I wasn't as specific).

Comment: *"...what is an example..."* What do you mean? Are you looking for a pre-existing library? Are you looking for a general use case?

Comment: @AJFarmar I'm looking for either something similar to the code I posted, or a documentation/example explaining how to check the type of a term in a String containing Idris code.

Answer (score 2):

There's an example of compiling a program via Idris as a library on this blog post.
https://brianmckenna.org/blog/idris_library

The `Idris` monad you see there is `StateT IState (ExceptT Err IO)` - IO with state and failure.
https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/src/Idris/AbsSyntaxTree.hs#L426
So it wouldn't be "pure", unless perhaps you  wanted to go lower level?

Comment: I meant pure in the sense of not using system calls (i.e., working with strings).

Comment: The commands on the blog you linked don't work for me. `cabal sandbox add-source ../Idris-dev` do not change the cabal file in any way (despite not showing an error). Trying to build the file gives import errors. Any suggestions? It has been a while since I last used Cabal.

Comment: @MaiaVictor The instructions given are for back when the commit that made Idris a library was just merged and you couldn't actually get it off Hackage. As of now, I'd imagine you'd just put `idris` in `build-depends`.

Comment: @pdxleif Link-only answers are not good answers. You should put enough *here* so that you can figure out what to do without having to follow the link (e.g. perhaps put a paraphrased version of the code block in the link here, and maybe even point out what the most important modules in the library do).

Comment: @HTNW thanks! Sadly I'm still not able to figure out how to make queries (typeof, evaluate, etc.) on Strings. Sorry if it should be obvious from those files.