# How to use Agda from the command line / from another language?

Tags: agda

Most interaction with Agda is done with EMACS, but is there a way to do it programmatically? I.e., is it possible to do everything from the command line, or from some API? The main goal is to build a thin wrapper so we could call Agda from another language, ex:

```
var Agda = require("agda");

var code = `
    data Bool: Set where
        true: Bool
        false: Bool

    not : Bool -> Bool
    not true = false
    not false = true

    val : Bool
    val = not true
`;

console.log(Agda.infer(code, "true")); // prints "Bool"
console.log(Agda.normalize(code, "val")); // prints "false"
```

I've previously asked how to use Agda [as a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330226/is-it-possible-to-use-agda-as-a-library), but that obviously only cover Haskell. I've tried looking Agda's VIM extension to see how it does it, and it seems like it is sending commands to Agda, but I'm not sure exactly how. Pointers to the relevant documentation would be highly appreciated!

Comment: [LUA Ting-Gan](https://github.com/banacorn) is currently adding a [JSON-based interaction backend](https://github.com/agda/agda/commits?author=banacorn) based on the reverse-engineering of the one for emacs. Sounds like you should talk to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, currently (on the master branch) there are two ways of interacting with Agda from the command line:

1. The original backend for Emacs `agda --interaction`
2. The new JSON-based backend `agda --interaction-json`

---

### The Emacs backend

- Emacs would send messages formatted as **Haskell datatypes** to Agda *(easy)*
- Agda would reply in the form of **Emacs Lisp** for Emacs consumption *(hard)*

As you can see, this backend was exclusively designed for Emacs.
It would take some reverse-engineering to figure out what they are talking with each other.

I've made [some notes](https://github.com/banacorn/agda-mode/wiki/Conversations-between-Agda-&-agda-mode) about the Emacs protocol when I was implementing [agda-mode on Atom](https://github.com/banacorn/agda-mode). But I'm afraid that it has deviated from the actual implementation at the time of writing.

Here are some relevant part of the Agda source code that you may find useful, if you want to interact with the Emacs backend:

- [Encoding Response as Emacs Lisp](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/Interaction/EmacsTop.hs#L60)
- [The datatype of Request](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/Interaction/InteractionTop.hs#L469)

---

### The JSON backend

Needless to say, it's painful to work with the Emacs protocol.
So I've managed to replace Emacs Lisp with JSON in the new backend.

- You would still need to send messages formatted as **Haskell datatypes** to Agda as you would in Emacs
- Agda would reply in **JSON**

Now, you wouldn't have to deal with the S-expressions of Emacs Lisp. 
This is how [responses are encoded as JSON](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/Interaction/JSONTop.hs)

---

However, the payloads are still serialized as strings, making it difficult to extract useful information from Agda. So I'm still working on [the `json` branch](https://github.com/agda/agda/tree/json), trying to [encode the payload](https://github.com/agda/agda/tree/json/src/full/Agda/Interaction/JSON) in JSON.

Comment: Thanks for working on this and for taking the time to explain it here!